# How find $\left(f^{ - 1}\right)'(1 + e)$ and $\int_1^{1 + e}\left[f^{ - 1}(x)\right]\ \mathrm {dx}$

Tags: real-analysis

How find $\left(f^{ - 1}\right)'(1 + e)$ and $\int_1^{1 + e}\left[f^{ - 1}(x)\right]\ \mathrm {dx}$,

where the function $ \begin{array}{c} f: [1,e]\rightarrow [1,1 + e] \\ \\f(x) = x + \ln x\end{array}$ is bijective?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**. For the first term note that $1 = (f^{-1} \circ f)' = (f^{-1})' \circ f \cdot f'$, hence 
$$ {f^{-1}}'(y) = \frac 1{f'(f^{-1}(y))} $$
For the second term, take a look at the rectangle $[0,e]\times [0,1+e]$, it can be split in three parts (draw a picture):

- The square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.
- The area under the graph of $f$, with size $\int_1^e f(x)\, dx$
- The area unter the graph of $f^{-1}$ (reflected at $y=x$), with size $\int_1^{1+e} f^{-1}(y)\, dy$.